# Avoid RecyclerView from showing scrollbar when notifyItemChanged being called

Tags: android

I notice that, whenever I call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(row);`, the scrollbar will be shown.

Is there any way to avoid such behavior? I prefer not to show scrollbar, during `adapter.notifyItemChanged(row);`. The below screenshot is how the scrollbar become visible, when `notifyItemChanged(row)` is called.

[image]

However, when the actual gesture scrolling happen, I still would like the scrollbar to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieve my desired requirement. Having `post` is the key to the solution.

```
recyclerView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
try {
    // Do something.
} finally {
    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Not sure whether if check is necessary.
            if (recyclerView != null) {
                recyclerView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line: `android:scrollbars="none"`

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

for temporary invisibility try this:

```
recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
adapter.notifyItemChanged(row);
recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: But, this will also cause scrollbar become invisible during actual gesture scrolling.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I edited my answer, I'm not sure about second part but try it please

Answer (score 0):

Set scrollbar size to 0 before calling notifyItemChanged and restore it afterwards:

```
int size = recyclerView.getScrollBarSize();
recyclerView.setScrollBarSize(0);
adapter.notifyItemChanged(row);
recyclerView.setScrollBarSize(size);
```